# Is the disparity from /camera/depth/disparity 11bit raw data?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,guys,

I need to do some advanced kinect calibration so I need raw data instead of processed depth data.
Any one know if /camera/depth/disparity is raw or not?
Thank you!

Ranqi

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/41401/is-the-disparity-from-/camera/depth/disparity-11bit-raw-data?/) by [ranqi](https://answers.ros.org/users/2941/ranqi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-08-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DiogoCorrea](https://answers.ros.org/users/933/diogocorrea/) on 2012-12-10**:
I have the same question. Do you know the answer now? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are you referring to the disparity image or the depth image published by the driver?

The depth image contains the distance from the camera to the scene along the z-axis (optical axis) of the camera. The ROS [openni_camera](http://ros.org/wiki/openni_camera) driver publishes the depth image as a:

- 16-bit unsigned integer, in millimeters, on `camera/depth/image_raw`,
- float, in meters, on `camera/depth/image`.

(see [depth_image_proc](http://www.ros.org/wiki/depth_image_proc))

The ROS driver does not publish the nonlinear, 11-bit raw output of the Kinect.

---

Originally posted by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) with karma: 4954 on 2012-12-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DiogoCorrea](https://answers.ros.org/users/933/diogocorrea/) on 2012-12-16**:
I was a little confused and I actually wanted to know if the disparity data published by ROS (/camera/depth/disparity) was the same raw data of libfreenect driver. Apparently are not the same.

Thanks for your answer.